# How can I make a parsed text clickable so that a popup window appears

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-button, popupwindow

I am relatively new to Android Studio. I want a popup window to appear not when clicking on a button, but when clicking on the text that I parsed from an xml-file.

```
    private TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        parseXML();
    }

    private void parseXML() {
        XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
        try {
...

    }

    private void processParsing(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
        ArrayList<foo> Sentence = new ArrayList<>();

... 

    private void printText(ArrayList<foo>Sentence) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (foo word : Sentence ) {
            builder.append(word.text).append(" "); //take elements from parsed data file 
        }

        txt.setText(builder.toString()); //write to txt for the screen
    }
```

So far I parsed an xml data file via the XMLPullParser. I do not display the parsing itself (I tested it and it works). The elements are in a list. These elements essentially appear on the screen just as a simple text. 
The next step should be like this: These elements must be clickable (basicaly, they  behave like a button, but for the user they do not look like a traditional button). Then an individual popup window should appear providing short informations to be specified separately.

My question: how can I make the text clickable?

Comment: You need to create individual `TextView`s for each word (list item) and set the `OnClickListener` on each `TextView`. Otherwise you'll need to implement a `ListView` with an adapter to handle that

Comment: Thanks! If I understand you correctly I need as many `TextView` s as I have elements in my list. But this is not possible since this list has several thousand elements. 
And as far as I saw in `ListView` it appears as a scroll-down-list. But since it is a readable text for an user, the text itself should stay as it is.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display this whole text from xml as a paragraph? and make each word clickable?

Comment: Yes, exactly this. I know it is a lot. But I already have such a big xml file. So I need an idea how to implement a lot of clickable environments efficiently. The xml file provides by definition an element separately. Any suggestion is appreciated!